# Is there a parallelism intended in Romans 9:4?

Tags: romans, literary-structure

Paul lists a string of six blessings on Israel in Romans 9:4 ([NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans+9%3A4&version=NIV)):

> Theirs is the adoption to sonship; theirs the divine glory, the covenants, the receiving of the law, the temple worship and the promises.

There seems to be a pause and restart in verse 9:5 (at least whoever versified the text also thought so). And some of the blessings are similar enough that one wonders whether there is a bit of parallelism going on here. But there seem to be two plausible ways to put the items in parallel:

**A B C C' B' A'**

With this structure Paul would be pairing the adoption to sonship with the promises, the divine glory with the temple worship, and the covenant(s)<sup>[see below]</sup> with the receiving of the law.

**A B C A' B' C'**

The alternative option would be to pair the adoption to sonship with the receiving of the law, the diving glory again with the temple worship, and the covenants with the promises.

Are these terms even intended to be parallel in structure and if so is there one of these structures that is to be preferred?

---

<sup>An answer to the [text critical question](/questions/32414) of "the covenant" vs "the covenants" probably helps decide this one and vice versa. So I'm particularly interested in answers that don't rely on determining that answer first.</sup>

Comment: A B C C' B' A' seems more likely.

Answer (score 1):

A look at the original Greek clarifies that the list is a simple list, not a parallelism:

> **Romans 9:4-5 (NA28)**
>
> οἵτινές εἰσιν Ἰσραηλῖται, ὧν ἡ υἱοθεσία **καὶ** ἡ δόξα **καὶ** αἱ διαθῆκαι **καὶ** ἡ νομοθεσία **καὶ** ἡ λατρεία **καὶ** αἱ ἐπαγγελίαι,
>
> ὧν οἱ πατέρες **καὶ** ἐξ ὧν ὁ Χριστὸς τὸ κατὰ σάρκα, ὁ ὢν ἐπὶ πάντων θεὸς εὐλογητὸς εἰς τοὺς αἰῶνας, ἀμήν.

My translation:

> [..my brothers according to the flesh] [namely] Israelites, of whom is the adoption of God as sons, **and** the glory, **and** the covenants, **and** the giving of the law, **and** the worship, **and** the promises;
>
> Of whom are the fathers, **and** from whom is Christ (according to the flesh): who God over all, blessed forever. Amen.

It likely that the list was simply getting too long, and as is proper to writing in general, you repeat the governing "of whom" or equivalent before continuing further. But there is *also* the fact that, fathers and Christs fleshly derivation from that lineage are presented as one, separate logical unit, especially for how verse 5 wraps things up: having Christ come of you is the most important thing here relevant to the importance of physical Israel. I am tempted to put a colon after "promises," in fact, to convey this thought pattern, but I think it's fine as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The first pattern you point to as a possible pattern is known as a [chiasic structure](http://www.newtestamentresearch.com/nt%20research-mk%202/chiastic_structuring.htm). It is used to draw attention to the center item and it was a common technique from my understanding. Notwithstanding its popularity, it features prominently in the Hebrew Bible, and the Pauline Epistles including Romans.

Given that fact alone it seems likely that Paul was using a smaller chiasic structure for this verse too, especially added to the fact that there is a large chiasm that provides an organizational framework spanning the whole of Romans.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we need to look at the entire context to get the proper view of Paul’s intended grouping. I believe the key lies in verses 3 and 5 with the reference to “the flesh” and then connect that to verses 6-8 and the discussion of the seed of Abraham.

Please note the King James (Young’s Literal as well) wording of Romans 9:1-5:

> I say the truth in Christ, I lie not, my conscience also bearing me
>   witness in the Holy Ghost, 2 That I have great heaviness and continual
>   sorrow in my heart. 3 For I could wish that myself were accursed from
>   Christ for my brethren, my kinsmen according to the flesh: 4 Who are
>   Israelites; to whom pertaineth the adoption, and the glory, and the
>   covenants, and the giving of the law, and the service of God, and the
>   promises; 5 Whose are the fathers, and of whom as concerning the flesh
>   Christ came, who is over all, God blessed for ever. Amen.

Paul starts off chapter 9 saying that he has great heaviness in his heart for his follow countrymen, Israel. In verse 3 he says that he wishes he was separated from Christ on behalf of his fellow countrymen who are his kinsmen “according to the flesh”; meaning in nationality only and not as members of the family of God by faith.

In verse 4, Paul relates 5 of the 6 attributes to Israel “according to the flesh”. These are the adoption, the glory, the convent (believe this is singular), the giving of the law and the service.  These all apply to Israel “after the flesh” in verse 3.

In verse 4, I believe the reference to “the adoption” is not the New Testament concept of adoption but a reference to Exodus 4:22 and Hosea 11:1:

> Ex 4:22-23:  And thou shalt say unto Pharaoh, Thus saith the LORD,
>   Israel my son, even my firstborn. Let my son go that he may serve me
>   and if thou refuse to let him go, I will slay thy son even thy
>   firstborn.”
>
> Hos: 11:1-2: When Israel was a child, then I loved him and called my
>   son out of Egypt as they called them so they went from them; they
>   sacrificed unto Balim and burned incense to graven images.”

Continuing in verse 4; The glory, I believe is a reference to the pillar of cloud by day and pillar of fire by night that led the tabernacle. The Covenant is the Covenant of the Law which flows into the giving of the law.  The reference to the “service of God” is a specific reference to the service in the Tabernacle in the wilderness.  All these attributes  are Old Testament concepts and tie to the Israel “after the flesh” (or the keeping of the law).

Finally, in verse 4, the reference to “the promises” connect to verse 5.  So the language would be "…and the promises (plural contrast to the other singular usages) whose are the fathers…”

Please note in verse 5, Paul says that the promises, whose are the fathers, connect to the flesh in Christ!  This is hugely significant.  Paul is contrasting Israel’s seed (by works) after its own flesh with Christ’s seed (by faith). Please look at verses 6-8:

> 6 Not as though the word of God hath taken none effect. For they are
>   not all Israel, which are of Israel: 7 Neither, because they are the
>   seed of Abraham, are they all children: but, In Isaac shall thy seed
>   be called. 8 That is, They which are the children of the flesh, these
>   are not the children of God: but the children of the promise are
>   counted for the seed.

These verses confirm the contrast of Israel “after the flesh” (in verses 3 and 4) with the real seed of Abraham, who the New Testament tells us are all who believe/trust in the sacrifice of Jesus Christ by grace/faith. These children of Christ, which are children of the promise are “counted” for the seed of Abraham.